# How to increase space between facet_wrap labels and panels in R ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

I want to increase the vertical space between the labels (setoda, versicolor and virginica) and their respective panels. How can I do this? The regular options like `panelspacing and margins` don't seem to have an effect.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)


ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
             geom_point()  +
facet_wrap( ~ Species) + 
theme(strip.text.x = element_text(face = "italic")) + 
theme(strip.background = element_blank())
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to increase the `margin` around the `strip.text`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap(~Species) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank())

p +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(
    face = "italic",
    margin = unit(rep(50, 4), "pt")
  ))
```

[image]

Or using `margin()` and increasing only the bottom margin:

```r
p +
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(
    face = "italic",
    margin = margin(4.4, 4.4, 50, 4.4, "pt")
  ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using panel.spacing() within theme() function increases space between panels. Here as example I set the unit= 3:

```
ggplot(data = iris, aes(x = Sepal.Length, y = Sepal.Width, color = Species)) +
  geom_point()  +
  facet_wrap( ~ Species) + 
  theme(strip.text.x = element_text(face = "italic")) + 
  theme(strip.background = element_blank()) +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(3, "lines"))# panel spacing
```

[image]